# getsockopt return negative mss (on CLion)

Tags: c, sockets, clion, getsockopt

I got an issue, when i use the function `getsockopt` to get the MSS i got a negative number (or 0). But the function is successfull, the socket is correct value `hSocketService` is correct and working.

So i got:

```
getsockopt OK
Taille maximale d'un segment = -13312
```

Here is the code:

```
int tailleMsgRecu, nbreBytesRecus, finDetectee, tailleS, tailleO;


 /* 7. Recherche du MTU  -*-Mache pas-*-*/
    tailleO=sizeof(int);
    if (getsockopt(hSocketService, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &tailleS, &tailleO) == -1)
    {
        printf("Erreur sur le getsockopt de la socket %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("getsockopt OK\n");
        printf("Taille maximale d'un segment = %d\n", tailleS);
    }
```

thanks

**EDIT**

I forgot to precise that I'm running the code on windows using cygwin with Clion.

I changed the code and now `tailleS` is of type `socklen_t`, and printing its value with `printf("Taille maximale d'un segment = %u\n", tailleS);`
the result is `Taille maximale d'un segment = 0`.

So the issue is still the same, I'm not getting the right value even if getsockopt is working.

Comment: At what point are you attempting this? Is the socket connected?

Answer (score 1):

Your `tailleS` variable must be of type `socklen_t` which resolves to an **unsigned** value on most platforms - You do, however, use a signed integer. This garbles the value.

Printing that value should be done with a `%u` format specifier to tell `printf` that this variable is unsigned.

And a last remark: You seem to be aware that what you're retrieving is NOT the MTU, but rather the TCP segment size which is a different thing (close, but still different)

Comment: With the changes you propose I just got this : `getsockopt OK
Taille maximale d'un segment = 4294953984`. Yes i know, and the tcp seg size is what i want so don't worry

Comment: And with tailleS of type socklen_t I got `Taille maximale d'un segment = 0`

Comment: Can you update your code above to what is *now* not working?

Comment: @RémiHirtz To do it properly, you also need to change `taille0 = sizeof (int)` to `sizeof socklen_t` - Although that probably won't make it work. What's your platform?

Comment: Ah. Cygwin. Most probably the code does not work because windows does not support that socket option (I cannot see it here): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Or rather specifically here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738596(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok so what option should I use to get the max segment size ? Because I don't see it in the IPPROTO_TCP Socket Options.

Comment: Simple truth: None. Doesn't work. Windows just doesn't cut it.